# Task Scheduler starts two tasks on Idle Trigger and on idle end one task does not close

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, scheduling

I am using command line to import two created xml files into the task scheduler whose purpose is to run never-ending batch files (keep running until terminated). Because they are never-ending I could not put multiple multiple commands into one task as they are run sequentially and I want them running simultaneously. Moreover, their goal is to start up one minute after the idle trigger has went off. Then, upon idle mode ending the tasks are supposed to end as well as the two batch files as I have both hard terminate and end on idle parameters set to true. However, only one of the batch files is closing leaving the other one still running.

My question is how can I solve the problem of only the one task from ending and not both of them or if it is closing but leaving the program open and making sure it closes it with the task.

Best Regards,

David Rohweder

Comment: what are these batch files doing that they run until terminated? what program is opening?

Comment: cryptocurrency mining applications

Comment: and the batch files just open your mining applications? I apologize if I'm not grasping the situation - I'm just trying to understand why you wouldn't just have the task open the mining application directly as opposed to having the task start a batch that opens the applications.

Comment: The batch files run the application, but the task scheduler is used to start and close them during an idle mode. The problem is I am opening two batch files through two tasks and on idle end one batch file does not close.